# SP10 couldn't log on Videntityinfo::isFreshToken reported failure

Tags: 2010, safe-controls

I had a problem of not being able to log onto my site

Looking in the logs I saw

> Videntityinfo::isFreshToken reported failure

and something about safe control load exception.

Couldn't work out what was going on. I left it a few days and when I went to try and fix it, it was working again and I could log on to the site as normal.

Anyone have any ideas on why this happened?

Comment: I am also facing the same error and for me, this shows in the ULS for about a min and then disappears. Because of this, the page takes more than a minute to load. Also, this issue is not consistent. Once I am on the site then it works fine. This issue is also not for all sites.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurred when you are accessing my site directly.It may be through bookmarking the url or other way, the site was implented with ADFS SP2010 Claims based authentication or NTML authetication, the token is not generated. When you access the other site and once you logged in, the ADFS now uses the Fed Auth cookie to login, it will not make new request for authentication.It works now as it uses Fed Auth token which is chached and created already.

To repro the issue, you can clear the cache from ADFS or your CA either with iisreset and other ways and login directly in to my site, the issue will repro.

Comment: I am also facing the same error and for me, this shows in the ULS for about a min and then disappears. Because of this, the page takes more than a minute to load. Also, this issue is not consistent. Once I am on the site then it works fine. This issue is also not for all sites. Is there a way I can fix this? Please let me know if I can find more details on the issue.